# how to change the size of the rows and columns of a matrix in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, wxpython

I have created a matrix using this bit of code

```
self.ax = self.fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
N = data.max()+5
self.ax.set_xlim(0,N)
self.ax.set_ylim(0,N)
self.ax.set_aspect('equal')
self.ax.scatter(data[:,1],data[:,0],color='black', marker = 's')
```

how can i change the size of the rows and columns so the points drawn are of a smaller size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `s = 1` parameter sets the size of the points drawn by `ax.scatter`:

```
self.ax.scatter(data[:,1],data[:,0],color='black', marker = 's', s = 1)
```